# How to set temporary dns if there are original permanent dns on mac osx

Tags: macos, dns

If there are original permanent DNS on mac 10.8.2 or 10.9, my app cannot set temporary DNS by “SCDynamicStore” API. But It could work on older osx version such as 10.5.4.
I have google all about Mac DNS setting but could not find a way to resolve this problem.
Do not know why permanent and temporary DNS cannot exist at same time on new mac osx. 
Is there any way to resolve it?